# Why does $f$ extend holomorphically to the unit disc?

Tags: complex-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Let $α ∈ (0, 1)$ be a fixed exponent, and let $C > 0$

Denote as usual by $D$ the unit disc, and suppose that $f$ is holomorphic on $D$ \ {$0$} , and $|f(z)| ≤ C/|z|^α$

Show that $f$ extends holomorphically to $D$.

My attempt:

I already have tgat $f$ is holomorphic on $D$ \ {$0$} . So I still have to prove that $f$ is bounded on $D$ \ {$0$}, because if that's the case, I can apply Riemann's Extension Theorem and  finally $f$ extends holomorphically to $D$

So, let $z=x+iy$ $\in$ $D$ \ {$0$} then $|z| = \sqrt{(x^2+y^2)} = 1$ because $D$ is the unit disc and thus $D$ = {$(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2+y^2 = 1$}.

Hence $|z|^α = 1$ and finally $|f(z)| ≤ C/|z|^α = C$ and thus $f$ is bounded on $D$ \ {$0$}. 
Therefore, $f$ extends holomorphically to $D$

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: $|z|=1$ means $z$ is on the _boundary_ of the unit disc.  I'm thinking maybe apply the maximum modulus principle.

Comment: You are confusing the unit circle $\{|z|=1\}$ and the (open) unit disc $\{|z|<1\}$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster how to apply this theorem here?

Comment: Well, according to the theorem, the maximum is achieved on that boundary.  Thus $f$ would be bounded by $C$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster could you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: Just that.  The hypotheses appear to be satisfied.  You could look it up.

Comment: @ChrisCuster the application is not so trivial, as the boundary of the region is $\{|z|=1\}\cup \{0\}$, and on $0$ we only know $|f(z)|\le +\infty$.

Comment: @Caffeine I see.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ is not directly bounded, as $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{C}{|z|^a}=+\infty$. However, we can mimic the proof of Riemann's Extension theorem (in some versions of the theorem this case is already considered, as @MartinR ntoted in the comments below):

We consider the function $g(z):=zf(z)$, it is bounded and so by Riemann's theorem is analytic in the complex unit disc. In particular, since $|g(z)|\le C|z|^{1-a}$, $g(0)=0$. Let $n$ be the order of this zero of $g$ (note that $n\ge 1$); we can write $g(z)=z^nh(z)$, with $h$ a holomorphic function which is nonzero near $0$. It is now trivial to verify that $z^{n-1}h(z)$ is an analytic extension to the unit disc of $f$.

Comment: That *is* Riemann's theorem on removable singularities, compare (4) in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann's_theorem.

Comment: @MartinR  Riemann's theorem is often stated as "bounded iff holomorphically extendable". I agree that your version is more general, but it evidently is not the version the O.P. has in mind.

Comment: Why is the function $g(z) = zf(z) $ bounded?

Comment: Because $|g(z)|=|z||f(z)|\le |z|\frac{C}{|z|^{\alpha}}=C|z|^{1-\alpha}$. The exponent $1-\alpha>0$, and thus, since $C|z|^{1-\alpha}\le C$ on the unit disc, $g$ is bounded.